# What IP java use when provide 0.0.0.0 as localAddress in Socket

Tags: java, sockets

In java to establish TCP connection, We required to create socket. 
I use below constructor to create socket.
[public Socket(InetAddress address, int port,InetAddress localAddr,int localPort) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29)

According to java API, localAddress should be a valid InetAddress or null. When i provided `0.0.0.0` as local address it will work correctly to establish connection on local machine e.g. `27.0.0.1` and also on remote machine.

To connect on local machine, Socket use `127.0.0.1`  and for remote machine, socket use `P1P1` interface address as local address.
I don't know how java manages to find appropriate IP address for connection. I look into java API but doesn't found any thing.

Comment: Have you checked this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Comment: Thanks jigar, I think 0.0.0.0 means "The Unspecified Address" e.g. it will try on all interface to communicate. Correct me if i wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't use anything. It passes what you supply directly to the operating system. I don't believe `0.0.0.0` is a valid local address for a connected socket, but if it is `INADDR_ANY`, which means 'use any local IO address'.

There are few occasions when you need to specify a local address or port when connecting a TCP socket. Just use the two-argument constructor.